# Token based authentication with BCrypt hashpassword

Tags: c#, asp.net, bcrypt, http-token-authentication

I am totally new to Asp.net mvc. I am trying to implement token based authentication on my Asp.net mvc app. I have implemented it successfully according to http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/
Where client generated token is sent with each http request. In the server side I process this token and get the data in it to generate a token in the server side to compare with. Where my token contains the data username, password, ip, user agent and time stamp. in the server side I get the username from client token and retriev the password from database to generate token in the server.
Now the problem is my application has changed to store encrypted password in the database using `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword`. Now the problem is using this BCrypt api I unable to decrypt the hash password to get the original password. So I have no idea how to generate the token in server side. Any ideas on this are highly appreaciated

Comment: That's basically the idea of a hash, that you can't reverse it. You can only compare two hashes to see if they are derived from the same input.

Comment: So for a given password, you calculate the hash and compare it with the hash in the database to see if passwords match.

Comment: Last comment: If you want token based authentication, use oauth or openid connect middleware for OWIN. Not something that someone has put together in a few hours which I think they did in that post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of a hash. You can hash a text string(password), but you can not reverse it and get the original input. This is because multiple text strings get hashed to the same hash. 
So there is no way to say what is the original input by looking at the hash.

To verify the user has input the correct password you can use `BCrypt.Verify("my password", passwordHash)`

It returns true if your new password matches with the hash. Please note that you cannot hash the password again and just check whether the two hashes are equal because for the same string you get different hashes each time as it adds a random salt value to the original string. So you have to use the `BCrypt.Verify` for checking passwords. You can choose a different schema for the token or encrypt the password and store in the database if you want to retrieve it later. But usually passwords are hashed when storing in the database for additional security.